# What does 太搭了 mean?

Tags: meaning

Came across this comment on the [douban page for *Isle of Dogs*](https://movie.douban.com/subject/26640371/):

> 掉线 看过 2018-04-16
>
> 【B】①日风和韦斯安德森太搭了，方方正正的建筑配上方方正正的镜头，带出强烈的仪式感。

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E6%90%AD) gives the definitions:

> 1 to put up
>
> 2 to build (scaffolding)
>
> 3 to hang (clothes on a pole)
>
> 4 to connect
>
> 5 to join
>
> 6 to arrange in pairs
>
> 7 to match
>
> 8 to add
>
> 9 to throw in (resources)
>
> 10 to take (boat, train)
>
> 11 variant of dā [褡]

I can't, accurately, figure out what 搭 means here.

Perhaps it's dialect?

Too fitting? Too suitable?

Comment: I think it means 太搭配了 (so amazingly suitable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

日风和韦斯安德森太*搭*了，方方正正的建筑*配*上方方正正的镜头，带出强烈的仪式感

A搭B，A配B，I gonna say, “搭”="配"，short for “搭配”, means 'match, fitting, suitable'.
Of course, it is not a dialect.

“太搭了”，means “perfect matching, amazing suitable”

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a dialect. It's pretty common actually. For example, 这件衣服和你的裤子很搭. Some would use 配， 这件衣服和你的裤子很配。but if you say 你和她很配，it connotes romantic relationship. If you tend to avoid the romantic, you should say 你和她很搭. 搭 means one thing/person can work well with another.

Answer (score 0):

> ①日风和韦斯安德森太搭了

It is a name, I do not know whose name but

> 搭

for sure means to match here.